# Error on calling parse.com cloud code from browser

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm trying to call from a browser with `Javascript` to `Parse.com` CloudCode. But, when I call it, JS sends me back an error like:

> Object {code: -1, message: ""};

Any idea?

This is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  Parse.$ = jQuery;
  Parse.initialize("XX", "XX");

  $('.form-horizontal').on('submit', function(e) {
    var enrll = document.getElementById("enNum").value;
    var keyNum = document.getElementById("key").value;

    Parse.Cloud.run("GetMonth", {
      enrollmentNbr: enrll,
      key: keyNum,
      month: ""
    },                {
      success: function(result) {
        document.getElementById("comment").value = result;
      },
      error: function(e) {
        //error
        console.log(e);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 700px;
}
.modal-header, h4, .close {
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color:white !important;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.modal-footer {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
.textarea {
  margin-left: 230px;
  margin-right: 230px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.13.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
  <h2>Add your key and your Enrollment number</h2>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header" >
      <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Credentials</h4>
    </div>
    <br />
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Enrollment number:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="enNum" placeholder="Enrollment number">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Access Key:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text"class="form-control" id="key" placeholder="EA Access Key">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="comment">csv</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="1000" id="comment" ></textarea>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/74dn34L7/

I know I don't arrive to Parse because the logs are not raised.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you add a snippet please? Or create a fiddle?

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/74dn34L7/

Comment: I can see that the error is: `{"error": "Please use POST request"}`

Comment: @MoshFeu I only had to put this {method: "POST"} like:

Parse.Cloud.run("GetMonth",
        {
          enrollmentNbr: enrll,
          key: keyNum,
          month: ""
        },{method: "POST"},{
          success: function(result) {
              document.getElementById("comment").value = result;
          },
          error: function(e) {
             //error
             console.log(e);
          }
        });

Thanks a lot!

Comment: My pleasure.. Happy to help ;)